# Prevent a class from being freed

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to pass a pointer to a class so some code I don't control.  This code automatically free()s the pointer when it is done, but I need the class later.  I hoped I could just make a 'wrapper' class that would keep the class from being deallocated without actually preventing the code from accessing it, but virtual calls don't work.

```
template <class T>
class PointerWrapper:public T
{
public:
    T* p;
    PointerWrapper(T *ptr)
    {
        p=ptr;
    }

    ~PointerWrapper(void)
    {
    }
    T* operator->() const
    {
        return p;
    }
    T& operator*() const
    {
        return *p;
    }
};

void codeIDontControl(Example *ex)
{
     ex->virtualfunction();
     delete ex;
}

void myCode()
{
    Example *ex=new Example();

    codeIDontControl(ex);
    do something with ex //doesn't work because ex has been freed

    codeIDontControl(new PointerWrapper<Example>(ex));
    do something with ex //ex hasn't been freed, but the changes made to it via 
    //    Example::virtualfunction() in codeIDontControl() aren't there anymore
}
```

Basically, ex->virtualfunction() calls the virtual function in PointerWrapper itself instead of the virtual function in PointerWrapper->p.  It seems that it's ignoring the -> operator?

Now, I don't need to use a PointerWrapper-esque class if there's a different way to do this, but it was all I could think of...

I can't modify Example either, but I can subclass it

Comment: You could make a defensive copy..e.g. allocate a clone and pass that, so that the delete frees the clone.

Comment: but then I wouldn't get the changes that codeIDontControl() makes to the class

Comment: Just so i'm clear, (1) you want to call a function that destroys the object passed by reference (as a pointer), (2) you don't want the object you passed to be destroyed, and above all (3) you don't own the code from (1). yeah, you're pretty much dorked. One final thought though, do you own the code for the object class of the *parameter* ?? i.e. in your example, the Example class ?

Comment: I don't own the parameter's class, but I *am* passing a custom subclass I do own

Comment: I still don't understand why there is a method that _changes_ your object and then _deletes_ it. What's the point?

Answer (score 4):

You should provide Forwarder class - which redirects virtual calls to stored pointer. Freeing of forwarder class will not cause releasing of pointee. This approach **does NOT need to do copy** (which can be expensive/may be not implemented/or even not make sense):

```
struct Forwarder : Example
{
    Example *impl;
    Forwarder(Example *i) : impl(i) {}
    void virtualfunction()
    {
        impl->virtualfunction();
    }
};
```

Full code:

[live demo](http://ideone.com/Ac3cS5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

struct Example
{
    virtual void virtualfunction()=0;
    virtual ~Example() {}
};

struct Implmenetation : Example
{
    bool alive;
    Implmenetation() : alive(true) {}
    void virtualfunction()
    {
        cout << "Implmenetation::virtualfunction alive=" << alive << endl;
    }
    ~Implmenetation()
    {
        alive=false;
        cout << "Implmenetation::~Implmenetation" << endl;
    }
};

struct Forwarder : Example
{
    Example *impl;
    Forwarder(Example *i) : impl(i) {}
    void virtualfunction()
    {
        impl->virtualfunction();
    }
};

void codeIDontControl(Example *ex)
{
     ex->virtualfunction();
     delete ex;
}

void myCode()
{
    Implmenetation impl;

    codeIDontControl(new Forwarder(&impl));
    //do something with ex //doesn't work because ex has been freed
    impl.virtualfunction();
}
int main()
{
    myCode();
}
```

Output is:

```
Implmenetation::virtualfunction alive=1
Implmenetation::virtualfunction alive=1
Implmenetation::~Implmenetation
```

Comment: +1, but only works if it's okay to have a dummy `Example` object floating around (as parent of Forwarder).

Comment: @bitmask - good point! Anyway, I think dummy Example in many situations is better than copying.

Comment: +1 this is a worthy work-around for what is internally a terrible design, and a not-so-intuitive way to address it. Good gray-matter stretch!

Answer (score 3):

It's bad design, really. Only the allocator should be allowed to free memory. Functions like this are dangerous, as they leave with with dangling pointers.

This is just off the top of my head, maybe you could try something like this? It's not a safe idea, but if someone implemented it I would be interested to know what happens.

```
class Foo
{
  Foo(Foo* copy) : m_copy(copy) {}
  ~Foo() { if(m_copy) { *m_copy = *this; } } // Use copy constructor to create copy on destuction.

  Foo* m_copy;
}


Foo copy(NULL);
Foo* original = new Foo(&copy);
MethodThatDeletes(original);

// Original should be destroyed, and made a copy in the process.
original = NULL;

// Copy should be a copy of the original at it's last know state.
copy;
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote the answer at least leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: +1 I think `copy` in your example should be a top-level object, and passed to the constructor by address, `Foo *original = new Foo(&copy);`. The object pointed to by `original` will be destroyed, but not before dumping into `copy`. The idea has merit, though management may be a little odd, esp for object lifetimes. An interesting idea, and worth an up-vote.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Ah of course, that was my intention. I made those changes. I would probably avoid something like this, but then again I don't think I've ever used a library that tries to delete my memory.

Comment: I agree with the basic idea of lifetime management but not really impressed by the code-snippet you provided. It's like one more band-aid rather than addressing the bad design

Comment: @Sarang - I'm pretty sure I made clear that I didn't think this is a good idea, and it is totally band-aid code. It's proposing an option, although it seems they are better solutions to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a Example* to codeIDontControl.  The overloaded operator-> on PointerWrapper is an for the PointerWrapper type not the Example* type or even the PointerWrapper* type (i.e. for a value or reference of that type not a pointer to that type).

Since the function you need to call isn't controlled by you, you will need to provide a complete wrapper of the type it expects as a wrapper over the instance you wish to control the lifetime of.